# Ubuntu 14.04 Suspend Resuming Issue

Tags: 14.04, screen, suspend

I've had a problem with the "Suspend" feature on Ubuntu, and generally when you get a problem you look online for a fix, which I have done and I haven't found a fix, all I have found is other people with the same problem. The only types of fixes I've found it by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> but even when I do the first part the screen still remains off

When I do try and "resume" from suspend everything seems to come back on except my screen. My sound works (because when you get to the login screen it makes some sound) and I see my Wi-FI turns on as well (from the button I have on my keyboard).

Just the only thing which isn't happening is the screen turning back on. Does anybody know how to fix this problem? It'll be a great help if you do!

I have a HP Pavilion (something) laptop. The Graphics card I have is a Radeon HD 7420G.

Comment: What type of computer do you have, and more importantly, what is your graphics card?

Comment: I have a HP Pavilion (something) laptop. The Graphics card I have is a Radeon HD 7420G, if that's any help?

Comment: Could be [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/1010683), which is linked to [this bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42162), which suggests trying `pm-suspend --quirk-test --quirk-s3-mode`

Comment: Tried that, everything went off (in suspend I guess) tried resuming, nothing came back at all...

Comment: Still in need of help people, can anyone help?